# SearchBar in table view with searchDisplayController programmatically no edit

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, edit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to create a tableview with a searchbar inside the header view of the table. I'd like to use a searchDisplayController to manage everything.
I've created everything programmatically (I'm not feeling comfortable with  IB) trying to set all the correct properties, but it seems that I'm missing something, because when the table shows up I'm not able to edit the text in the searchbar and see any animation.
Here is a part of the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchBar *searchBarTMP=[[UISearchBar alloc]init];
    self.searchBar=searchBarTMP;
    [searchBarTMP release];
    self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    self.searchBar.delegate=self;
    self.searchBar.showsScopeBar=YES;
    self.searchBar.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    self.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.searchBar.multipleTouchEnabled=YES;

    self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"City",@"Scope City"),NSLocalizedString(@"Postal Code",@"Scope PostalCode"),nil];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView=searchBar;
    self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex=0;
    self.navigationItem.title=NSLocalizedString(@"Store",@"Table title");

    //SearchDisplayController creation
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayControllerTMP = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchDisplayController=searchDisplayControllerTMP;
    [searchDisplayControllerTMP release];
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate=self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate=self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource=self;  

    //....continue
}
```

I know that when you use a searchbar alone you must deal with its delegate protocol, but I'm guessing that the searchDisplayController manage for you as seen in the Apple sample code. (build up with IB).

Any suggestion?
Thank you,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it...
After putting in the header of the table view must write

```
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, make sure you create an iVar for the UISearchDisplayController in your header file.

If you create an UISearchDisplayController using:

`UISearchDisplayController* searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchField contentsController:self];`

it will get released by ARC, it will not call any delegate methods and when you'll call `self.searchDisplayController` (the UIViewController's property) it will be `nil`.

So, the fix is:
In your header (.h) file:

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {
        UISearchDisplayController* searchDisplayController;
        UISearchBar *searchField;
        UITableView* tableView;
        NSArray* searchResults;
}
```

and in the implementation (.m) file:

```
searchField = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 49)];
searchField.delegate = self;

searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchField contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

tableView.tableHeaderView = searchField;
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, searchField.frame.size.height);
```

When implemented like that, you can call both `self.searchDisplayController` and `searchDisplayController` in the rest of your code.